# Mapping a filtered list of tuples gives an error in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections, case-class

I use scala and have a case class defined as

```
case class caseClass(aString :String, bInt :Int, cClass : Class[_], dClass : Class[_], eClass : Class[_])
```

and then I have code to get a set of M from a list of classes

```
classes.filter(
  clazz => clazz.isInterface
).map(
    klazz =>  (
      klazz.getDeclaringClass,
      klazz,
      klazz.getDeclaringClass.getDeclaredClasses.filter(
        klass => klass.getSimpleName.equals("PythonJ")
      ).head
      )
  ).zipWithIndex.map { case ((service, iteratr, privte), port) => caseClass(
    s.getName, port, service, iteratr, privte
  )
}.toSet
```

But when I try to compile this code it gives an error saying

```
constructor of type (T1, T2, T3) cannot be uniquely instantiated to expected 
type Tuple3 [Class[?], Class[?], Class[?]]

 --- because ---

 undetermined type

 ).zipWithIndex.map { case ((service, iteratr, privte), port) => caseClass(
                             ^
```

Can someone tell me what I have to do to make this correct

Comment: I can understand that you might want to hide some of your logic to the public but can you please improve your variable naming please? First, it hurts the eyes but secondly, it would give us more context and easiness to read. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aurélien Thieriot is right, you need to assist the compiler - but in a different place:

```
classes.filter(
  clazz => clazz.isInterface
).map(
    klazz =>  (
      klazz.getDeclaringClass,
      klazz,
      klazz.getDeclaringClass.getDeclaredClasses.filter(
        klass => klass.getSimpleName.equals("PythonJ")
      ).head
      ): (Class[_],Class[_],Class[_]) // <--type spec
  ).zipWithIndex.map { case ((service, iteratr, privte), port) => caseClass(
    service.getName, port, service, iteratr, privte
  )
}.toSet
```

This will (in my understanding) help by fixing the type parameters of the result of `map`  into existential types, which makes the subsequent type inference result unambiguous (i.e. the compiler will not be forced to infer "`Class` of *what*?").

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that the compiler is not able to infer the type.

Did you try by specifying the type you are expecting? Something like:

```
).zipWithIndex.map { case ((s: Class[_], i: Class[_], p: Class[_]), port) => Module(
```